# pinpoint should be fix at center in map, by moving the map in background and retrieve the location by getting lattitude and longitude

Tags: android

I hav a requirement that after displaying the map I should fix the pinpoint at the center of the map. While moving the map the pinpoint should not be moved, map should be move on background. After that where the pinpoint is that location should be retrieved and returned. 
Can any one please help me on this

Thanks
Amulya